# "Invalid Credentials" when accessing BigQuery through PHP API using service account

Tags: php, google-api, google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

I'm attempting to access Big Query through Google's php API using a service account.

```
<?php

require_once '../google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_BigqueryService.php';

define("CLIENT_ID", 'removed-removed.apps.googleusercontent.com');
define("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME", 'removed-removed@developer.gserviceaccount.com');
define("KEY_FILE", '../../../key.p12');

define("PROJECT_ID", removed);

$client = new Google_Client();

$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);

$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
                SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction'),
                $key)
);

$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);

// Instantiate a new BigQuery Client 
$service = new Google_BigqueryService($client);

try
{
    $service->tables->listTables(PROJECT_ID, "data");
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

> Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/removed/datasets/data/tables:
>   (401) Invalid Credentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct OAuth scope - the scope in the code above is for the Google Prediction API. Use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery` for full access to the BigQuery API. More about BigQuery API [authorization here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization).

Example:

```
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
                SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'),
                $key)
);
```

Comment: That was it. Was looking at the service account tutorial for the prediction API. Thanks.